# Http post - Connection reset while sending large data vc++

Tags: c++, http, visual-c++, mfc, connection

My Code needs to post the xml data to the server using vc++ , am using CInternetSession for post and tinyxml for xml.

If my xml data is about 8 kb the data is posted really good. But if the xml file size is around 15 kb then am receiving "The connection to the server was reset".

```
TiXmlDocument doc( "C:\\test.xml" );
bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile();

if ( loadOkay )
{
    TiXmlPrinter printer;
    printer.SetIndent("\t");
    docs.Accept( &printer );

    docs.Print();
    CString zURLstest = printer.CStr();

    #define MAX_READ_BUFFER 102400

    CInternetSession* p_CInternetSession;
    CHttpFile* p_HttpFile;
    CStdioFile* p_File;
    char z_ResponseBuff [MAX_READ_BUFFER];
    ULONG ul_ReadLen;
    CFile cFResponce;

    p_CInternetSession = new CInternetSession(NULL,1,PRE_CONFIG_INTERNET_ACCESS,NULL,NULL,0);
    p_CInternetSession->SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,10000);
    p_CInternetSession->SetOption(INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES, 3);

    CString zURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x/Test/TestServlet?Data=";
    CString zDWURL(zURL + zURLstest);

    p_File =  p_CInternetSession->OpenURL(zDWURL, 1, INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY|INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE);           

    AfxMessageBox(zDWURL);

    p_HttpFile = (CHttpFile*)p_File;
    ul_ReadLen = p_HttpFile->Read (z_ResponseBuff, MAX_READ_BUFFER);

    DWORD dwError;
    p_HttpFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwError);

    if(dwError==200)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Data updated successfully");

        remove(c:\\test.xml");
    }
}
```

Any ideas, or suggestions to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a POST, it's a GET request with all of the data stuck into the URL. Most servers will have a limit on URL length for a variety of reasons. And the server's response if you exceed this limit will be to summarily disconnect you with prejudice on the theory that you're trying either a DDOS or buffer-overflow exploit.

Looking at the documentation for [CInternetSession::OpenURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d25ew7sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [CHttpFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/tzhfwc94%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it's really clear that you can't use `OpenURL` for this. It has no way to let you specify the (as the documentation calls it) verb to use for your HTTP request.

You're going to have to figure out a way to use the [HttpOpenRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead. This looks much more complicate as you'll have to pick the URL into its component parts yourself. Maybe the library has some nice URL parsing functions you can use to do this.

I must say that this is a really horribly designed library.

Comment: sorry am new to this, thats wat made me confused. However i cannot able to post the xml data to the server

Comment: @user1441251: So, there are two main methods used to get data to an HTTP server. One is GET (which is what you're using) in which the data is encoded in a URL. But GET should only be used for requests that don't modify anything on the server, and because the data is encoded in the URL it can only be used for requests with a relatively small amount of data (a search query for example). You need to figure out how to get your framework to use a POST request instead.

Comment: @user1441251: I did some poking about in the MFC documentation for you and found out what methods you had to use at least.